# How do I clear localStorage with a button?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I want to make a button, who clears the localstorage for a user. using `localStorage.clear();` but it don't work.

If you look the demo, it don't work.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/w5umz17n/5/)

```
JS code:

var money = 0;

//localStorage function

if(localStorage.money) money = localStorage.getItem('money');
document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = money;

//Clicking function

function moneyClick(number){
    money = parseInt(money) + 10;
    document.getElementById ("money").innerHTML = money;
    localStorage.setItem('money', money);
}

//clear data function

function clearClick(number){
    localStorage.clear();
}
```

Comment: Works fine for me. Only problem I see is you don't update your DOM after you clear storage. What problem are you seeing?

Comment: It works, you need to refresh the page or set `money` to `0` and update the element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does clear`localStorage`, you need to refresh the page to see that though. In your code you can make it more clear by setting `money` to `0` and updating the DOM when you clear `localStorage`:

```
function clearClick(number){
    localStorage.clear();
    money = 0;
    document.getElementById ("money").innerHTML = money;
}
```